# Is it possible to somehow provide a remote path to the libraries used in a c++ program while compiling and linking?

Tags: c++, c, unix, ubuntu

Usually when I use a c++ library  I give the header file for the library using the `-I` attribute while compiling and link the library using `-l` attribute. But if the libraries are on another remote computer, and I do not want to copy or install it on my local host, is there some way to reference them on your local host?

Operating system:

- Localhost Host: Ubuntu
- Remote system: Unix Server

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @RogerRowland edited the question with the details.

Comment: You will need to mount the remote location over the network. Compiler are in general not network-aware, you have to supply locally accessible files to them.

Comment: @n.m. So will it work if I mounted the folders from the remote system onto my localhost using sshfs?

Comment: @VivekVK: Should do. If you're using GCC, then use the `-L` option to specify the directories to search for libraries.

Comment: If you really, really want to avoid mounting the remote fs, you could try `mknod thelib.ext p` / `g++ ... thelib.ext ... &` / `ssh remotehost 'cat .../thelib.ext' > thelib.ext` (or perhaps just `scp remotehost:.../thelib.ext .`) seems like it ought to work but I haven't tested it.

Comment: @TonyD doesn't what you say actually copy the library onto the local host?

Comment: @MikeSeymour Alright will try that.

Comment: sshfs will do but may be slowish. Use Samba or NFS if you can.

Comment: @VivekVK anything eventually has to copy the file content over... the idea with the named pipe was that it could buffer it as the compiler read it out so the entire file wouldn't need to exist at one instance on your machine, but thinking about it a little more - the compiler may well seek into it and read sections repeatedly - I don't think a FIFO pipe would work, so was probably a bad suggestion.

Comment: @TonyD good point on the copy.What was I thinking? :)

Comment: @n.m. Yeah tried SSHFS. It is woeful. Will try NFS. Thanks